# Ubuntu requirements.txt

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

ERROR: Couldn't find version that satisfies the requirement python-apt==2.0.0+ubuntu0.20.4.4(from version:0.0.0,0.7.8)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-apt==2.0.0+ubuntu0.20.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Update the  OS .
sudo apt update .
sudo apt upgrade .